# Why bootstrap toggle button only clickable for first time in modal dialog?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toggle

Bootstrap toggle button only worked for first time after close and open for second time the toggle button is unable to toggle. And it works again after open for third times.

```
 <input checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
```

What's wrong with the code? Any solution?

```
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
```

Launch modal1

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 1 title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <input checked data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you please share your problems code on codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: @ZahidulIslamRuhel jsfiddle no got this problem...

Comment: can you add full code? here

Comment: @ZahidulIslamRuhel Is there any bug for this? because it is fine when using outside modal dialog

Comment: The toggle button unable to toggle after close modal dialog for first time.

Comment: ok let me check on my editor...

Comment: what do you want to toggle by input checkbox?

Comment: @ZahidulIslamRuhel just toggle value 1 or 0, when on then 1 when off then 0.

Comment: i'm not getting what actually you want to do...
where want show this value?

`when checkbox is checked you what value 1 and when unchecked you want value 0.. `
do you want this?

Comment: @ZahidulIslamRuhel sorry, and yes when check then value = 1 when unchecked value =0.

Comment: See this link : https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/yPJzoO

`This is what you want?~

Comment: @ZahidulIslamRuhel Yeah, but i am using bootstrap toggle.

Comment: I update it for you now check the link: https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/yPJzoO
`And please let me know~

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution:

```
    <button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Modal</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal 1 title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>
             <input checked type="checkbox" id="toggle-check" data-toggle="toggle">
         <span class="checked">Value 1</span>
         <span class="unchecked">Value 0</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.unchecked{
    display: none;
}
.toggle.off ~ .unchecked{
    display: inline-block
}
.toggle.off ~ .checked{
    display: none;
}
```

**Here is preview link:** https://codepen.io/ziruhel/pen/yPJzoO

For re-initialize bootstrap-toggle plugin in modal, so add this code:

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('#toggle-check').bootstrapToggle();
})
```